# Type hinting Vue template slots in PhpStorm

Tags: vue.js, phpstorm, webstorm, jsdoc

I am trying to figure out how to type hint my scoped slots in the template.

For example I have:

```
<template #item="{ item }">
```

In PhpStorm, I would like to be able to use properties of `item` such as `item.prop1` but PhpStorm doesn't know what the type of `item` is.

The type of `item` is variable between components, so I cant define what it is where I define the slot, using `@binding`.

I tried to use the regular JSDoc syntax in the template via:

```
<!-- @type {object} -->
```

But this did not work.

Is there a way to document scoped slots within the template of a component?

I am not using TypeScript.

Comment: no, can't think of any way to achieve this:(

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
<template #item="{ item } : { item: Record<string, string> }">
```